# Why the disabled="disabled" is not working in following scenario?

Tags: html, smarty, disabled-input

My code from smarty template is as below. The disable="disabled" property is not working on text fields. Can you tell me why it's not working?

```
<input type="text" name="{$sheet_type}_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}_{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}_{$key_diff_lvl}" id="{$sheet_type}_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}_{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}_{$key_diff_lvl}"  maxlength="3" class="mini" value="{$diff_level.added_no_questions}" disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: try only using `disabled` instead of `disabled='disabled'`

Comment: If Smarty is somehow essential to the problem, describe how, and give more details; if not, remove the tag. If using PHP is relevant, describe how; if not, show an HTML-only example (with no PHP variables) that actually reproduces the problem. Explain what you mean by “not working” and which browser(s) you used for texting.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="{$sheet_type}_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}_{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}_{$key_diff_lvl}" id="{$sheet_type}_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}_{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}_{$key_diff_lvl}"  maxlength="3" class="mini" value="{$diff_level.added_no_questions}" disabled="disabled">
```

checked like this.. And it is working fine.

You can also mention only `disabled` but as per my knowledge, in XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the `disabled` attribute must be defined as `<input disabled="disabled" />`